# CSSNext postcss-custom-media - unable to import medias from file with 'importFrom' option

Tags: postcss, cssnext

I'm trying to add [customMedia](https://cssnext.github.io/features/#custom-media-queries) [option](https://github.com/MoOx/postcss-cssnext/blob/master/src/features.js) to my postcss-cssnext [features](https://cssnext.github.io/usage/#features) config with `importFrom` file location, but that doesnt work and I dont have any errors on project build, only final `Missing @custom-media definition for '--small-viewport'. The entire rule has been removed from the output.` when I'm trying to use the media. How do I debug this?

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-import')(),
        require('postcss-nested')(),
        require('postcss-simple-vars')({
            variables: {
                ...require('./src/ui/variables')
            }
        }),
        require('postcss-cssnext')({
            features: {
                customProperties: false,
                browsers: ['> 0.5%, last 2 versions, Firefox ESR, not dead'],
                customMedia: {
                    importFrom: require('path').join(__dirname, './src/ui/custom-media.css')
                }
            },
        }),
        require('cssnano')({
            autoprefixer: false,
            zindex: false,
            reduceIdents: false,
            discardComments: { removeAll: true },
            discardUnused: { fontFace: false },
            colormin: false,
        }),
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so as per [postcss-custom-media CHANGELOG](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-media/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) importFrom was added only in 7.0.0 while my cssnext uses 6.0.0. As CSSNext is deprecated I will switch to `postcss-preset-env`

Answer (score 0):

you know how to use custom media in postcss-preset-env, they work for me only if you create a custom media in the component and refer to it if I want to take custom media from index.css or vars.css they do not work , with variables everything is fine

Comment: you should post another question - I'm unable to provide code here

Comment: config ```const customMediaUnprefixed = require('./src/hooks/useMedia/custom-media.js');

const customMediaCache = {
 customMedia: Object.assign(
  {},
  ...Object.keys(customMediaUnprefixed).map((key) => ({[`--${key}`]: customMediaUnprefixed[key]}))
 ),
};

const config = {
 plugins: [
  require('postcss-preset-env')({
   stage: 0,
   customProperties: false,
   browsers: ['> 0.5%, last 2 versions, Firefox ESR, not dead'],
   importFrom: [customMediaCache],
   features: {
    'color-mod-function': {unresolved: 'warn'},
   },
  }),

 ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: custom-media.js ```module.exports = {
 sm: '(max-width: 719px)',
 md: '(min-width: 720px)',
 lg: '(min-width: 1280px)',
 xl: '(min-width: 1920px)',
 mdHeight: '(min-height: 550px)',
 lgHeight: '(min-height: 768px)',
};
```